# Cannot align figure to left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the `figure` to left and have the text on the same line to right, this is my html:

```html
<div class="container px-0">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></h2>
    <figure class="image image-style-align-left"><img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/500/442/354/outrun-vaporwave-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg"></figure>
    <p style="margin-left:0px">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
```

I tried with different properties such as:

```
figure { 
  float: right;
  text-align: right;    
}
```

but the `figure` still take the full row width. How can I fix that?

Comment: Please help adding information to your question as that you cannot change HTML structure. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS WILL DO I THINK
//Add this style

```
figure {  
display: inline;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: I applied this style but nothing change

Comment: figure {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
        } this will do.

Comment: `display: inline` is entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your `figure` block is inheriting 40px of left margin from the user-agent stylesheet (at least, that's what I see here). To remove this, apply `margin: 0` in your own stylesheet and you should find that the figure is aligned to the left as you want.

To debug this sort of issue, your browser's Inspector tool is invaluable. Right-click on the element you're interested in and choose "Inspect element" and you'll get a whole range of information including the calculated size, margins and padding, as well as a detailed view of all the styles that are being used on the element.

===Edit with snippet===

```html
<div class="container px-0">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></h2>
    <figure class="image image-style-align-left" style="margin:0;"><img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/500/442/354/outrun-vaporwave-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg"></figure>
    <p style="margin-left:0px">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
```

===Edit 2===

OK, so you've shared more info about your problem - specifically that you can't change the HTML, and that you want the text block flowing to the right of the image block. Assuming that's accurate and you can only make changes to the CSS file, the best you can do will be something like this:

```css
.row .figure {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.row p {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

If you prefer not to use floats but a different scheme like flexbox, the principle will be the same. But you're going to have major issues with precision in your selectors: apply a style to `figure` or `p` and it'll apply everywhere, of course. So if you can't add specific classes or even `id` tags to the relevant blocks, you may be out of luck.

Comment: I set `margin: 0` still same problem, what do you suggest?

Comment: I used your snippet and just added `style="margin:0;"` to the `figure` element and it's left aligned (see edited answer above). I don't know why you're seeing something else, I'm afraid.

Comment: I've updated my answer in light of the extra info you've shared @sfarzoso. Does this get you where you need to be?

Answer (score 1):

From your CSS classes from the snippet, I believe you use Bootstrap so I inserted Boostrap 5.0.2 to the snippet and fix the structure a bit along with an adjustment on the `max-width` on the image inside `figure`

```css
figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container px-0">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <figure class="image image-style-align-left"><img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/500/442/354/outrun-vaporwave-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg"></figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <p style="margin-left:0px">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
          up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
          Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from
          a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original
          form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Cannot change html structure unfortunately

Comment: So what can you change? Can you add/remove classes from elements? Or do you have control only over the css? You really need to share restrictions like that in the question because it makes a *huge* difference to the answers. (You should also share things like frameworks you're using, like Bootstrap!)

Comment: If you cannot change the structure, will you be able to control over their classes? If not, I don't think we can provide a robust answer to it.